# Links not working in multipage site with node.js and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am having trouble with my multi-page website in node.js/ejs.  I presume it’s a route problem but I believe my routes are set up correctly.  My index page renders fine but when I try to follow a link on the page, I get a “Cannot GET /” error.

My relevant front-end code:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
<a class="button_horizontal" href="index.ejs">HOME</a>      
<a class="button_horizontal" href="about.ejs">ABOUT</a>
<a class="button_horizontal" href="portfolio.ejs">PORTFOLIO</a>
<a class="button_horizontal" href="events.ejs">EVENTS</a>
</nav>
```

My relevant node.js code:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view options', __dirname + '/views/pages/layout');
app.set('images', __dirname + '/public/images');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000,function(){
    console.log("We have started our server on port 4000");
});

// Load website
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { });
});
```

And my file structure:

```
views/
    index.ejs
    about.ejs
    portfolio.ejs
    events.ejs
public/
    css/
    images/
    js/
routes/
    index.js
    users.js
```

I’d be very grateful if anyone can spot what I’m missing as I can’t seem to find any tutorials that use more than one page for the website!

Comment: I think there are issues with in `<a>` tag. You should not have .ejs extension  in `href` because we are not directly rendering .ejs files, nodejs has to render according to route. So, you need to mention the '/' or '/about' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work because in `<a class="button_horizontal" href="index.ejs">HOME</a>` you are pointing to `index.ejs` page, not to any route of node.js application.

Instead, you should have

```
<a class="button_horizontal" href="/">HOME</a>      
<a class="button_horizontal" href="/about">ABOUT</a>
<a class="button_horizontal" href="/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
<a class="button_horizontal" href="/events">EVENTS</a>
```

and in **app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', { });
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about', { });
});
app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res) {
   res.render('portfolio', { });
});
app.get('/events', function(req, res) {
   res.render('events', { });
});
```

Let me know, if you have any doubt.

Comment: you might need to also remove the ejs -extension from the links. Not sure though. (edit: like you did, sorry too fast)

Comment: Haven't I removed it ?

Comment: I should have read this hours ago. Thanks @MukeshSharma